# Настройка кнопки поиска в форме в разных обозревателях

Tags: html, css

Верстаю форму поиска такого вида

[image]

Не получается настроить местоположение кнопки "искать": во всех браузерах она получается расположена по-разному http://jsfiddle.net/T33sw/5/. Подскажите, как можно отрегулировать местоположение кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heidel, я делаю следующим образом:

```
<div class="search>
    <input type="text" ....>
    <button></button>
</div>

.search{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0; /* 20px это ширина кнопки поиска, можно сделать побольше что бы текст не был вплотную к кнопке поиска*/
    ...
    }
.search input{
    width: 100%;
    ...
    }
.search button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 20px;
    background: url('...');
    ....
    }
```

Надеюсь смысл понятен

Comment: ну, я  так понимаю, вы задали абсолютное позиционирование для кнопки? или что-то еще?

Comment: Да. Но это решение удобно тем что текст не налезет на кнопку, как у решения рядом. И ширина поля 100%, т.е. ширину всего можно регулировать через .search. И так как кнопка абсолютно запозиционирована, то не надо париться насчет vertical-align двух соседних инлайн элементов

Comment: да, понятно, большое спасибо))